# Increment value in a subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a document in my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59bd65b281a24497a0b3b401"),
    "user_id" : "1",
    "is_placed" : false,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "product_id" : 1,
            "units" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "product_id" : 2,
            "units" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to increment value of `'units'` for `product_id = 1`. Here is what my code looks like:

```
        MongoClient mongoConnection = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

    try {
        MongoDatabase db = mongoConnection.getDatabase("mydb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("orders");
        BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        whereQuery.put("user_id", "1");
        whereQuery.put("is_placed", false);
        whereQuery.put("product_id", 1);
        BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("items.units", 1);
        BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue);
        collection.updateOne(whereQuery, intModifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It does not throw any error. But neither does it increment the value. How do I achieve it? Also, is it possible to increment it only if `product_id = 1` exists else put `product_id = 1`?

Comment: Try to embed your code in a try catch block. You can tell what's happening

Comment: @Curcuma_ nothing. No exception

Comment: don't you need whereQuery.put("items.roduct_id", 1) instead?

Comment: @Curcuma_ tried it. Gave me com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: cannot use the part (items of items.units) to traverse the element exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For updating an embedded document in an array, you should use [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_). I cannot see you use it anywhere in your code. Your code may be, should be like this:

```
MongoClient mongoConnection = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

try {
    MongoDatabase db = mongoConnection.getDatabase("db");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("orders");
    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("user_id", "1");
    whereQuery.put("is_placed", false);
    whereQuery.put("items.product_id", 1);
    BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("items.$.units", 1);
    BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue);
    collection.updateOne(whereQuery, intModifier);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this works! How to make this possible along with the second question I asked: is it possible to increment it only if product_id = 1 exists else put product_id = 1?

Comment: @rishi it is not possible via one update query. Because if `product_id=1`does not exist, querying part of the update won't match the actual document. But you can do this: 1- do `updateOne`and check if writeResult > 0. 2- if writeResult = 0 then you can `push`product_id = 1.  May be you can do it with `aggregation`. But I would do this in application level via 2 queries instead of aggregation. Don't forget to upvote too :)